# Randomly generate += or -= javascript

Tags: javascript, random, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

Hi i am trying to assign either += or -= to an object position.
Firstly I have random math choosing a number:

```
var min = 9;
 var max = 11;
 var pos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
```

I am trying to add the out come of pos to this._target.position.z and this._target.position.x but I want it to be randomly either added or subtracted

so the random out come should be for the Z position should be either:

```
this._target.position.z += pos;
```

or

```
this._target.position.z -= pos;
```

and then for the X position should be either:

```
this._target.position.x += pos;
```

or

```
this._target.position.x -= pos;
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) * 2 - 1` is either -1 or 1, just multiply by `pos` and add it to your coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to randomly do `x += value` or `x -= value` you can simply use the first version, and then multiply your value by `-1` if you want to do a `-=`.

In other words:

```
const isNegative = // however you determine this, eg. Math.random
const newValue += (isNegative ? -1 : 1) * value;
```

Or, to apply it back to your case, using @Chris G's suggestion in the comments:

```
 const oneOrNegativeOne = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) * 2 - 1);
 this._target.position.x += oneOrNegativeOne * pos;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a condition based on a random event like this :

```
if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)) {
    //the condition return 0 or 1 for false or true
    this._target.position.z += pos;
} else {
    this._target.position.z -= pos;
}
```

and either for `this._target.position.x`